# How can I compute this sum of a series?

Tags: summation

After some long derivations with a certain 1D Hamiltonian, I end up with the following sum
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{e^{an^2(1+\frac{b}{4n^2-1})}-1}$$
But I am completely stumped by the $(1+\frac{b}{4n^2-1})$ term.
Is there any trick I can use to compute this sum?

I am interested in the behavior of the sum with respect to $a$

$a$ and $b$ are positive constants.

Comment: Similar questions were asked and answered a lot. Try numerically: `f[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := 
 NSum[1/(Exp[a*n^2*(1 + b/(4 n^2 - 1))] - 1), {n, 2, Infinity}]`, then e.g. `f[0.4, 0.5]` results in `0.264993`.

Comment: thank you for your comment @user64494 , I was in fact wondering If I could get an analytical result, to say physical things about my problem, I am interested in the behavior of the sum with respect to the $a$ parameter

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that an analytical result is possible?

Comment: @bbgodfrey, absolutely not

Comment: Given that even the much more simple $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{e^{n^2}}$$ does not have an analytical result, I don't see much hope in the posted sum having any analytical result.